# PHP pass by reference/value - question

Tags: php

I was going to explain to our intern the difference between "pass by reference" and "pass by value" in PHP, and did this simple script:

```
$a=5; 
$b=&$a; 
$a=8; 
echo $b;
// prints  8
$a=5; 
$b=$a;  //no &
$a=8; 
echo $b;
// prints 5
```

However, running this in php-cli using php -qa yields:

```
php >     $a=5; 
php >     $b=&$a; 
php >     $a=8; 
php >     echo $b;
8
php >     // prints  8
php >     $a=5; 
php >     $b=$a;  //no &
php >     $a=8; 
php >     echo $b;
8
php >     // prints 5
```

Should not the `$b=$a;` unlink $a and $b?

... so I got curius, and tried:

```
php > $b=3;
php > echo $a;
3
```

So, how did I get this wrong? What's going on here? It seems the reference-setting is somehow sticking, even though it should be cleared at the line `$b=$a`? I also tried:

```
php >    $e=5; $f=$e; $e=6; echo $f; 
5
```

...Which works as expected.

`$a` and `$b` seems linked permanently? Am I missing some big point here? How do I "unlink" the `$a` and `$b` variable?

Comment: Have you tried `unset($b)` before the second part?

Comment: Don't re-use variable names in the same scope if you don't explicitly mean the same.

Comment: +1 because this questions shows how trying to explain something to newbies can help you understand it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should the reference be cleared if you assign a value to a variable? It works like this (with semi-simplified comments):

```
$a = 5;    // creates a "slot", puts 5 in it, makes $a point to it
$b =& $a;  // makes $b point to the same "slot" $a points to
$c = 6;    // creates a "slot", puts 6 in it, makes $c point to it
$a = $c;   // puts the value of the slot $c points to into the slot $a points to
echo $b;   // outputs the value of the slot $b points to (6)
```

It's assigning a *value* to a *variable*. Whether the value is *literal* (`5`) or the *value held by another variable* doesn't matter. The reference stays until you `unset($b)`.

Comment: Thanks for the many comments here:) and your explanation is very good deceze. I assumed (obviously incorrect) that $b=$a would make a new slot for $b with a copy of the value of $a, but I see now that would probably be terribly unefficient. 

Thanks anyway! Jonas

Comment: @user Efficiency is not really the issue, rather that's how it's logically supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yeah, because you created `$b` as a reference to `$a`. So, what you're doing on the line:

```
$b = $a
```

is just assigning 5 to $a, because `$b` still references `$a`.

If you'd want to 'unreference' it, you'd have to `unset` and recreate the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first time your code makes any use of $b, it creates the variable $b and links it to the location of $a. Subsequently you're writing values into the shared location. You can't undo what location a variable references.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment...  I ran your script - and it did output '8' in both cases.  I added `unset($b)` after the first `echo` and ran again - now the output was 85, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do `$b = $a`, as $b is a reference to $a you're doing `$a = $a` in fact. As told by other people, you'd have to `unset($b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using more speaking variable names make this more clear to you:

```
$value = 5; 
$alias = &$value; 
$value = 8;
echo $alias;   # 8
$value = 5; 
$alias = $value; # no &
$value = 8;
echo $alias;   # 8 (OP expected 5)
```

This is easier to read, right?

Take a note especially on this line:

```
$alias = $value; # no &
```

What does happen here?

As `$alias` is an alias to `$value`, you're basically writing:

```
$value = $value;
```

Which is 5 at this stage.

Then you set `$value` to 8.

The `$alias` is still referring to `$value`.

If you want to stop `$alias` being an alias to `$value`, you can turn it into an alias to something else:

```
$alias = &$other;
```

Or just unset the reference:

```
unset($alias);
```